# How do I make a method in a vb generic interface that returns an instance of the implementing class?

Tags: vb.net, generics, interface

In Visual Basic, I want to create an interface that includes a function that returns an object of the implementing class. That is

```
public interface I
  function maker as ???
end interface

public class X
  implements I
  function maker as X
    return new X()
  end function
end class

public class Y
  implements I
  function maker as Y
    return new Y()
  end function
end class
```

Is there a way to say that? I suppose I could always say that `maker` returns an `I` rather than an `X` or a `Y`, but then callers would have to cast it. I thought of defining the interface as

```
public interface I(of ii as I)
```

But the whole point in doing this was so I could create a generic class that uses an `of I`, and if I say that, then the compiler insists on an infinite regression `of I(of I(of I...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly, but you can do this:

```
Public Interface I(Of T)
    Function Maker() As T
End Interface

Public Class X
    Implements I(Of X)

    Public Function Maker() As X Implements I.Maker
        Return New X()
    End Function
End Class
```

Or, like this:

```
Public Interface I
    Function Maker() As I
End Interface

Public Class X
    Implements I

    Public Function Maker() As I
        Return New X()
    End Function
End Class
```

Neither of these options *force* the derived class to return an instance of their own type, but they *allow* you to implement it that way.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but I'll give you the vote for right answer until such time as I do try it and find it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

This is where you need the "curiously recurring" type declaration:

```
Public Interface I(Of T As I(Of T))
    Function Maker() As T
End Interface

Public Class C
    Implements I(Of C)

    Function Maker() As C Implements I(Of C).Maker
        Return New C
    End Function
End Class

Sub Main
    Dim First As I(Of C) = New C
    Dim Second As C = First.Maker

End Sub
```

As Steven says, this still doesn't force the declaring type to use itself as `T`, but at least now `T` definitely implements `I`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. I tried to do this, and when I tried to create an instance of the interface, VS wouldn't let me because I got stuck in an infinite loop on the "of"s.

Comment: I have updated to a complete compilable example (except for the outer `Module`).